# Can json schema be used to validate based on input data

Tags: jsonschema

I'm just wondering if it is possible to use json schema to do validation of input data BASED on the actual input data itself.

Say I have an object:

```
{
parts: {
    123: {
        happy: 'me'
    }
},
cells: [{
    part_id: 123,
    some: 'other property'
}, {
    part_id: 124,
    some: 'thing else'
}]
}
```

Can I write a json schema that ensures that the part_id of the cell objects actually corresponds to one of the part objects passed in?

In other words, `part_id: 123` would be acceptable, but `part_id: 124` wouldn't be.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing a bit of research, it looks like JSON Schema v5 has the functionality already via the `$data reference` attribute.

The following is from the javascript schema validator, ajv:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ajv#data-reference

**$data reference**

With v5 option you can use values from the validated data as the values for the schema keywords. See v5 proposal for more information about how it works.

**$data reference** is supported in the keywords: constant, enum, format, maximum/minimum, exclusiveMaximum / exclusiveMinimum, maxLength / minLength, maxItems / minItems, maxProperties / minProperties, formatMaximum / formatMinimum, formatExclusiveMaximum / formatExclusiveMinimum, multipleOf, pattern, required, uniqueItems.

The value of "$data" should be a relative JSON-pointer.

Examples.

This schema requires that the value in property smaller is less or equal than the value in the property larger:

```
var schema = {
  "properties": {
    "smaller": {
      "type": number,
      "maximum": { "$data": "1/larger" }
    },
    "larger": { "type": number }
  }
};

var validData = {
  smaller: 5,
  larger: 7
};
```

This schema requires that the properties have the same format as their field names:

```
var schema = {
  "additionalProperties": {
    "type": "string",
    "format": { "$data": "0#" }
  }
};

var validData = {
  'date-time': '1963-06-19T08:30:06.283185Z',
  email: 'joe.bloggs@example.com'
}
```

$data reference is resolved safely - it won't throw even if some property is undefined. If $data resolves to undefined the validation succeeds (with the exclusion of constant keyword). If $data resolves to incorrect type (e.g. not "number" for maximum keyword) the validation fails.